# Transpose or pivot data

Tags: python, pandas

I'm busy busy with a project where I am trying to transpose/pivot data to change the structure of the data to make it more readable.

The source data looks like this

```
Date                      Text         DTMF        ID          CallerId
2021-06-22 09:49:08.22                 Answer      unique_1    1111111111
2021-06-22 09:49:08.263   Question 1               unique_1    1111111111
2021-06-22 09:49:14.35                 Call Ended  unique_1    1111111111
2021-06-22 09:13:50.233                Answer      unique_2    2222222222
2021-06-22 09:13:50.277   Question 1    2          unique_2    2222222222
2021-06-22 09:14:08.82    Question 2    3          unique_2    2222222222
2021-06-22 09:14:23.823   Question 3    4          unique_2    2222222222
2021-06-22 09:14:39.9                  Call Ended  unique_2    2222222222
2021-06-22 10:56:29.637                Answer      unique_3    3333333333
2021-06-22 10:56:29.727   Question 1               unique_3    3333333333
2021-06-22 10:56:30.133                Call Ended  unique_3    3333333333
2021-06-22 14:02:33.03                 Answer      unique_4    4444444444
2021-06-22 14:02:33.07    Question 1    1          unique_4    4444444444
2021-06-22 14:02:35.197                Call Ended  unique_4    4444444444
2021-06-22 08:57:10.267                Answer      unique_5    5555555555
2021-06-22 08:57:10.31    Question 1    2          unique_5    5555555555
2021-06-22 08:57:28.07    Question 2    3          unique_5    5555555555
2021-06-22 08:57:43.45    Question 3    4          unique_5    5555555555
2021-06-22 08:57:59.95                 Call Ended  unique_5    5555555555
```

The result I am trying to achieve is this

```
Date                    ID          CallerId    Question 1  Question 2  Question 3
2021-06-22 09:49:08.22  unique_1    1111111111          
2021-06-22 09:13:50.233 unique_2    2222222222  2            3           4
2021-06-22 10:56:29.637 unique_3    3333333333          
2021-06-22 14:02:33.03  unique_4    4444444444  1       
2021-06-22 08:57:10.267 unique_5    5555555555  2            3           4
```

The date I retain is the date in relation to the text column where it equals 'Answer'.

I could achieve this in apps script using the java script switch case statement but understand that this is not part of the python language.

I tried using the **groupby** and **pivot_table** functions of pandas but i get an error saying `DataError: No numeric types to aggregate`. In my case I'm not looking to aggregate any of the columns but just restructure the way it is presented.

Does anyone know of a suitable way to handle this? Appreciate the assistance

Comment: "I tried using the `groupby` and `pivot_table` functions" - _how_ did you try this? What code did you write?

Comment: Hi @ ForceBru. I pretty much used what was suggested below. There was an error in the source data I originally posted though. Essentially,  the DTMF column actually has int's and strings apposed to just int's. I think this may be where the issue lies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is probably a more elegant solution, but this works:

```
pt = df[df["Text"].str.len()>0].pivot(index="ID", columns = "Text", values="DTMF")
result = df[df["DTMF"]=="Answer"].reset_index().drop(["Text", "DTMF"], axis=1).merge(pt, on="ID").set_index("Date")
>>> result
                               ID    CallerId Question 1 Question 2 Question 3
Date                                                                          
2021-06-22 09:49:08.22   unique_1  1111111111                   NaN        NaN
2021-06-22 09:13:50.233  unique_2  2222222222          2          3          4
2021-06-22 10:56:29.637  unique_3  3333333333                   NaN        NaN
2021-06-22 14:02:33.03   unique_4  4444444444          1        NaN        NaN
2021-06-22 08:57:10.267  unique_5  5555555555          2          3          4
```

Comment: Legend @not_speshal. This definitely does the job. Can't say I fully understand what you have done hear but it will solve my problem. Thanks for the effort.

Answer (score 0):

This should be just a simple pivot but the default `aggfunc` used by `pd.pivot_table()` is `np.sum`. Hence your previous error. If you have multiple answers to the same question in the raw data, the `aggfunc` below will just concatenate them together with spaces.

```
import pandas as pd

table = pd.pivot_table(df, values='DTMF', index=['Date', 'ID', 'CallerId'], 
                       columns=['Text'],
                       aggfunc=lambda x: ' '.join(x)).reset_index()
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @ Taylrl. this is how I originally approached this, except with out the reset_index() argument. I'm still really new to Python so I haven't seen that before. I still got the same error though. There was a mistake in the original source data I posted and I think this may be the reason why. The DTMF column actually has strings and int's. I've updated the source data now to reflect this. Do you think this is the reason why?

Comment: I have edited my answer in-light of your comment

Comment: @Taylrl - I don't get OP's expected output using your code snippet.

Comment: Thanks @Taylrl. This still doesn't get me to my desired result. I am going to look to transform the source data to what I originally posted and test the first answer you posted to see if that works. Thanks for the insights.